# Div height inexplicably 5px taller when containing two images side by side

Tags: html, css, layout

I can't seem to figure out why this extra 5px is showing up at the bottom of my div when it contains two images. It does not happen when it only contains one image. I have removed all other markup and css and the problem remains. Also it happens on Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="<?php echo THEMES_URI; ?>starter_digital/style.less" type="text/css">
    <script src="<?php echo THEMES_URI; ?>starter_digital/javascript/less-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="social">
        <img src="<?php echo THEMES_URI; ?>starter_digital/images/facebook.png" />
    </div>

    <br />

    <div id="social">
        <img src="<?php echo THEMES_URI; ?>starter_digital/images/twitter.png" />
    </div>

    <br />

    <div id="social">
        <img src="<?php echo THEMES_URI; ?>starter_digital/images/facebook.png" />
        <img src="<?php echo THEMES_URI; ?>starter_digital/images/twitter.png" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Less / Css:

```
#social {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Result:

[image: Image of the error in Chrome]

Comment: You have a tool such as Firebug right? Just hover the DOM elements and it will show you where such passing and margin originates.

Comment: Aside from float left, try `vertical-align: top;`

Comment: Yes I do, and I tried that first. There is no padding or margin, the height is calculated with the extra 5 pixels for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trying adding:

```
#social img { display: block; float: left; margin-right: 5px; }
```

or

```
#social { line-height: 0; }
```

to your CSS. Since an `<img>` is an inline element by default, it's height is calculated differently as related to the default line-height value.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Gs3Q/

On inline elements, the line-height CSS property specifies the height that is used in the calculation of the line box height.

On block level elements, line-height specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/line-height

Comment: Sounds fair, but why does it only happen when there are two images?

Comment: In which browser were you seeing the issue not existing with only one image? Also, is what you've included in your question the only CSS that was present when you noticed this issue?

I can't seem to replicate this behavior.

Comment: Yes the files I included are the only files needed to replicated the issue for me in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. It looks just like it does in the above picture on all 3. As you can see in the picture the extra 5px shows up only on the bottom example where there are 2 images, but not when there is only one. Your fix worked, I'm just wondering why this effect only happens when there are multiple images.

Comment: @Aloxis - It's not the fact that you've got two images, it's the white space (line break) between them that causing the extra pixels beneath. See http://jsfiddle.net/wP9tL/1/. The full CSS explanation's a bit complicated, but since you're using XHTML Transitional doctype, the baseline of the first line box of the div doesn't get established until that white space gets rendered. Then the images sit on the baseline, and space is allocated for character descenders (on p, q, y etc) beneath the baseline, which is the extra pixels. XHTML Strict works differently. See http://jsfiddle.net/wP9tL/2/

Comment: That explains everything! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe changing the line-height might fix the problem.

```
#social {
   background-color: red;
   line-height:normal;
}
```